# How to build OpenCV (+contrib) as *.a libraries?

Tags: opencv, webassembly

I am writing web assembly in C++. I would like to integrate some methods from OpenCV into my application.

I am trying to build OpenCV as described here: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/da1/tutorial_js_setup.html in the section "Building OpenCV.js from Source".
I use the Windows Subsystem for Linux.

I use the command:

emcmake python3 ./platforms/js/build_js.py build_js --emscripten_dir=/mnt/c/Linux/emsdk/upstream/emscripten --opencv_dir=/mnt/c/Linux/opencv/ --build_wasm --cmake_option="-DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/mnt/c/Linux/opencv_contrib/modules/"

When the build is done, I have *.a files in the build_js/lib folder. But there are not all modules from contrib. I am interested in the ximgproc module.

In some preparation for the build, I have:

Wrapped in JavaScript(js):
--     opencv_core
--     opencv_imgproc
--     opencv_photo
--     opencv_dnn
--     opencv_features2d
--     opencv_calib3d
--     opencv_objdetect
--     opencv_video
--     opencv_wechat_qrcode
--     opencv_aruco

ximgproc has not been included in this list, but later

OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:     .... ximgproc ...

As a result, I have libraries (*.a) from the list "Wrapped in JavaScript(js):" only. ximgproc.a library was not built.

Is it possible to build ximgproc from contrib as *.a library?

When a build is finished, how to collect all OpenCV header files into 1 folder?

Include folder contains only:
include/opnecv2/opencv.hpp
include/CMakeLists.txt

Thanks

Comment: Looking at the source code, the generation of JavaScript wrappers for `ximgproc` is not supported yet: https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/8dfeed73b9389ba09411498dc1e923431d7fe292/modules/ximgproc/CMakeLists.txt#L2 (there's no `js` following the `WRAP` token). Whether it's just a matter of adding `js` to that list, or whether it would be more involved to get it working, I cannot tell at such a quick glance.